# How to change the value of private variable in java

Tags: java

I started to programm in Java since Yesterday, and I have the biggest question of my entire programmer life(since Yesterday).

For example, let's say I have a code like this:

```
public class itsAClass {
    static private String A;

    public static void main() {
        A = "This should be changed";
    }

    public String something() {
        return A;
    }
 }
```

I wanted to use the method `something()` in another Class to get the String Sentence of `A`, but I got only `null`.
How can I change the value of `A`, so that the another Class can get the Value `"This should be changed"`?

Comment: You will need to make access modifyers i.e getters and setters.

Comment: i dont see that code you are reffering to

Comment: You would need to call `main()` for starters.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to bring this code to work you just can make something() static as well.

But this will be not the right way to approach this problem.

If you want to hold code in the main class you could do something like this:

```
public class AClass {
    private String a;

    public static void main() {
        AClass myC = new AClass();
        myC.setA("This should be changed");
        
        // than use myC for your further access

    }

    public String something() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

If you want to access it by a external class without direct reference you can checkout the singleton pattern.

```
public class AClass {
    private final static AClass INSTANCE = new AClass();

    private String a;

    public static void main() {
        getSingleton().setA("This should be changed");
    }

    public String something() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static AClass getSingleton() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This way you can access it via AClass.getSingleton() from any location of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your `main()` function.

In another class:

```
itsAClass aClassObj = new itsAClass();

aClassObj.main();
// or rather itsAClass.main() as it is a static function
// now A's value changed

System.out.println(aClassObj.something());
```

Answer (score 0):

the way to set the value of private variable is by setter and getter methods in class.

example below

```
public class Test {
   private String name;
   private String idNum;
   private int age;

   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public String getIdNum() {
      return idNum;
   }

   public void setAge( int newAge) {
      age = newAge;
   }

   public void setName(String newName) {
      name = newName;
   }

   public void setIdNum( String newId) {
      idNum = newId;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call method main() in method something().

```
public class itsAClass{
    static private String A;

    public static void main() {
        A = "This should be changed";
    }

    public String something() {
        main();
        return A;
    }
     public static void main(String[] args){
        itsAClass a1 = new itsAClass();
        System.out.println(a1.something());// prints This should be changed
    }
 }
```